# Какие варианты разворота строки?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Хочу написать функцию, не используя срезы, не используя метод reverce и функцию reverced, не создавая пустой массив при этом. Знаю можно использовать стандартный алгоритм замены символов с предварительным портированием. Какие еще могут быть варианты?

```
def reversed_string(s):
    chars = list(s)
    for i in range(len(s) // 2):
        tmp = chars[i]
        chars[i] = chars[len(s) - i - 1]
        chars[len(s) - i - 1] = tmp
    return ''.join(chars)

data = reversed_string('stroka')
print(data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def reversed_str(origin_str):
    return ''.join(origin_str[index] for index in range(len(origin_str) - 1, -1, -1))

print(reversed_str('1234567'))  # '7654321'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def wqe(st):
    try: s = st.pop(-1)
    except IndexError: return
    yield s
    yield from wqe(st)
print(''.join(wqe(list('abcdef'))))  # fedcba
```

Answer (score 0):

Вариант воспользоваться подходящей структурой данных, а именно колодой/деком, загружаем и обратно извлекаем в порядке обратном загрузке:

```
class Deque:
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []

    def add(self, item):
        self.items.append(item)

    def get(self):
        return self.items.pop()

text = '1234567890'
my_obj = Deque()

for i in text:
    my_obj.add(i)
for j in range(len(text)):
    print my_obj.get()
```